# Unresolved import in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have an error importing map (java.util.Map). It's weird because the JRE path is configured correctly. I'm using Java 6.0, eclipse 3.6, JRE 1.8. Any suggestions?

Comment: How could be using both Java 6.0 and JRE 1.8? Do you mean you are compiling for Java 6 compatibility using the Java 8 compiler?

Comment: Do you have a class named `Map` in the same package maybe?

Comment: I don't have a class named Map..

Comment: I meant I use Java SE 6.

Comment: Go to project properties -> Java Build Path and see if Eclipse is reporting any errors there. You are likely referencing a JRE that doesn't exist from your project.

Comment: Java SE 6 but JRE 1.8. Do you mean you have JDK 1.6 and JRE 1.8 installed??

Comment: Yes. That was the problem

Answer (score 0):

if your CLASSPATH is set correctly you should be able to use any of java classes. by  either using an import statement such as
import java.util.Map;

or referring to your Map object with its fully qualified name
as in the following snippet

java.util.Map myMap = new java.util.HashMap();

which compiles on my machine when inserted into some anonymous java program.

If this does not work, 
check your environment variables.

Comment: what should I look for through the environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

I should have used JRE 6 instead of 1.8. That solved it.